# Detecting when a child window loads "each" time it do so

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, parent-child, onload

I am trying to add some page load-checking functionality to a parent,child windows using Javascript.

My goal is to detect "from the parent window", each time the child window fully loads then execute some code.

I use the following code sample on my parent window :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

childPage=window.open('http://www.example.com');

childOnLoad=childPage.addEventListener('load', LoadAndGo, true);

function LoadAndGo()
{
    if(confirm("Press a button")==true)
    {
        //childPage.removeEventListener ("load", childOnLoad, false);
        childPage.top.location.href="http://www.example.com";
        //childOnLoad=childPage.addEventListener('load', LoadAndGo, true);
    }
}
</script>
```

The previous Code attaches and detects load event to my child window, then it redirect it to another page "after I click the confirm button",

What I want to do is to make the parent window detects the next child loads,
i.e. detect the load after the redirect.

I tried to remove, then re-attach a new `onload` event "the commented lines", but it seems the 
parent window detects the First child-load only.

So the flow should go like:

Parent opens Child
Parent detects Child load
Parent redirect the child
Parent detects again the child load
.
.
and so on

- I own the two pages which share the same domain and protocol.
- No JS should be executed on the child window "i.e. child window can't check it's loads and pass data to parent window".

Answer (score 0):

Did re-binding after causing the child to navigate not work?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var childPage = window.open('http://www.example.com');

    childPage.addEventListener('load', LoadAndGo, true);

    function LoadAndGo()
    {
        if(confirm("Press a button") == true)
        {
            childPage.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";

            // Re-bind
            childPage.addEventListener('load', LoadAndGo, true);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Nope, it's the same problem as before, the parent detected the first load, but not the one after the redirect.